# R: mean function not working?

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a simple calculation with my `mean` function. When I input `mean(1, 10, 100)`, R returns `1`, which is obviously not the correct average. It always returns the first entry of my vector. What went wrong?

Comment: it doesn't return the first entry of your vector because you are not giving it a vector. see `?c` and `?vector`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `mean(c(1,10,100))`

See http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/functions/c